# Books recommended as requisites for understanding general relativity to the fullest?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

Saw some questions here which asks for what a student should know but couldn't find a complete list of recommended books for the maths and physics one needs to know. The answers can serve as a journey to a college fresher where to start from and how to go ahead.

Comment: I am not looking for the books on relativity but on the foundations of maths and physics. The answer that its being pointed to describes only relativity books.

Comment: You need some first year calculus, differential equations and linear algebra. That should be enough for GR.